# Add and Subtract a value using scripted buttons

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to do something very simple and straight forward in google sheets. I was able to perform this on Excel, but just haven't resolved it in sheets

I have a sheet with stock figures for printer cartridges. Next to the total of cartridges available i want to add a 'plus' and 'minus' button (i have the buttons in place ready) what i want them to do is add or minus 1 to the figure in the total box. I just cant work out the script at all.

I did it in Excel using the following

**Sub Button1_Click()
Range("A1") = Range("A1") + 1
End Sub**

But that doesn't work at all in sheets.

Please dont mock me for this, I am a complete new comer to scripting so very much learning the tricks of the trade.

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps

Comment: How many buttons are there?  Just one?  Does the row with the total ever move to another row?  Is this just one formula, or a formula in every row?

Comment: Its going to have a + and - button for each toner, so around 20 lines. The total box will never move. The script below has worked, just need to do for each button now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the Tools menu and click Script Editor. Copy and paste the following code.

```
function plus() {
ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
s=ss.getActiveSheet()
var currVal=s.getRange("A1").getValue()
var plusVal= currVal +1
s.getRange("A1") .setValue(plusVal)
}
function minus() {
ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
s=ss.getActiveSheet()
var currVal=s.getRange("A1").getValue()
var minusVal= currVal -1
s.getRange("A1") .setValue(minusVal)
}
```

From you sheet right click on the shape (button) and click the arrow. From the menu select Assign Script. Enter plus (for the plus button). This is the function name for the plus function. Repeat for the minus button assigning the minus function.
The first time you run the script you will see two popups. Continue and Accept in the popup windows.

Comment: Excellent, that has worked a treat, would never have got there myself. Cheers

Comment: You can mark this as the correct answer so that the green check mark shows.  You get a couple points for marking it as correct.